# looping throught the entire table to check for values sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure for updating a record which satisfies certain condition. I want to check if the passed value is contained in the table. I am using

```
declare @disp_sname varchar(100);
declare @disp_type varchar(100);
declare @disp_sub_type varchar(100);
declare @disp_date date;

select @disp_sname= voucher_sname,@disp_type=voucher_type,
@disp_sub_type=voucher_sub_type,@disp_date=voucher_date
from voucher_master
```

which is returning just the last row value.

My entire stored procedure is

```
    USE [new_esatnam]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spUpdateVoucherNo]    Script Date: 08/13/2012 13:36:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateVoucherNo] 
(
@voucher_id as int,
@voucher_separate_numbering as varchar(2),
@voucher_method_numbering as varchar(2),
@voucher_last_number as int,
@voucher_sname as varchar(15),
@voucher_type as varchar(2),
@voucher_sub_type as varchar(2),
@voucher_date as datetime,
@company_code as varchar(50),
@updated_by as int,
@updated_on as datetime
)   
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @disp_sname varchar(100);
declare @disp_type varchar(100);
declare @disp_sub_type varchar(100);
declare @disp_date date;

select @disp_sname= voucher_sname,@disp_type=voucher_type,
@disp_sub_type=voucher_sub_type,@disp_date=voucher_date
from voucher_master

if @disp_sname=@voucher_sname and @disp_type=@voucher_type and @disp_sub_type=@voucher_sub_type and @disp_date!=@voucher_date
BEGIN
update voucher_master set voucher_type=@voucher_type,voucher_sub_type=@voucher_sub_type,
voucher_sname=@voucher_sname,
voucher_separate_numbering=@voucher_separate_numbering,
voucher_method_numbering=@voucher_method_numbering,
voucher_date=@voucher_date,
voucher_last_number=@voucher_last_number,
company_code=@company_code,
updated_by=@updated_by,
updated_on=@updated_on where voucher_id=@voucher_id 
END
if @disp_sname!=@voucher_sname
BEGIN
update voucher_master set voucher_type=@voucher_type,voucher_sub_type=@voucher_sub_type,
voucher_sname=@voucher_sname,
voucher_separate_numbering=@voucher_separate_numbering,
voucher_method_numbering=@voucher_method_numbering,
voucher_date=@voucher_date,
voucher_last_number=@voucher_last_number,
company_code=@company_code,
updated_by=@updated_by,
updated_on=@updated_on where voucher_id=@voucher_id 
END

return @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

I want my stored procedure to satisfy this condition

```
 voucher_type    voucher_sub_type     date        voucher_sname
 INV                DOM              1/1/2000       ID            allowed
 INV                DOM              15/1/2000      ID            allowed

 INV                INT              1/1/2000       ID            not allowed
 INV                INT              15/3/2012      ID            not allowed
```

Voucher Sname should be allowed for same voucher_type and voucher_sub_type with different date and the same voucher_sname should not be allowed for different combination of voucher_type and voucher_sub_type.

Any ideas how my sp will satify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this in your first aql query --voucher_id=@voucher_id

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateVoucherNo] 
        (
        @voucher_id as int,
        @voucher_separate_numbering as varchar(2),
        @voucher_method_numbering as varchar(2),
        @voucher_last_number as int,
        @voucher_sname as varchar(15),
        @voucher_type as varchar(2),
        @voucher_sub_type as varchar(2),
        @voucher_date as datetime,
        @company_code as varchar(50),
        @updated_by as int,
        @updated_on as datetime
        )   
        AS
        BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @disp_sname varchar(100);
        declare @disp_type varchar(100);
        declare @disp_sub_type varchar(100);
        declare @disp_date date;

DECLARE @minid int,@maxid int
select @minid=min(voucherid),@maxid=max(voucherid) from voucher_master 

while(@minid <= @maxid)
BEGIN
        select @disp_sname= voucher_sname,@disp_type=voucher_type,
        @disp_sub_type=voucher_sub_type,@disp_date=voucher_date
        from voucher_master where voucher_id=@minid

        if @disp_sname=@voucher_sname and @disp_type=@voucher_type and @disp_sub_type=@voucher_sub_type and @disp_date!=@voucher_date
        BEGIN
        update voucher_master set voucher_type=@voucher_type,voucher_sub_type=@voucher_sub_type,
        voucher_sname=@voucher_sname,
        voucher_separate_numbering=@voucher_separate_numbering,
        voucher_method_numbering=@voucher_method_numbering,
        voucher_date=@voucher_date,
        voucher_last_number=@voucher_last_number,
        company_code=@company_code,
        updated_by=@updated_by,
        updated_on=@updated_on where voucher_id=@voucher_id 
        END
        if @disp_sname!=@voucher_sname
        BEGIN
        update voucher_master set voucher_type=@voucher_type,voucher_sub_type=@voucher_sub_type,
        voucher_sname=@voucher_sname,
        voucher_separate_numbering=@voucher_separate_numbering,
        voucher_method_numbering=@voucher_method_numbering,
        voucher_date=@voucher_date,
        voucher_last_number=@voucher_last_number,
        company_code=@company_code,
        updated_by=@updated_by,
        updated_on=@updated_on where voucher_id=@voucher_id 
        END

SET @minid=@minid+1
END

END
```

Comment: Is this different from the OPs code? If so, might be worth highlighting where you've made changes

Comment: I have just added this(where voucher_id=@voucher_id) in the where clause of the first sql select.

Comment: Here to loop through you can use the while loop based on min and max of voucher_id

Comment: Not clear what you want here.You can provide some sample data and explain what exactly sp has to do.

Comment: select @disp_sname= voucher_sname,@disp_type=voucher_type,
@disp_sub_type=voucher_sub_type,@disp_date=voucher_date
from voucher_master -- here why are you not applying where claues?

Comment: I don't want to check only for that id but the entire table for the voucher_sname